# Is a function of $\mathbb N$ known producing only prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, divisibility

It is well known that a polynomial $$f(n)=a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2+\cdots+a_kn^k$$ is composite for some number $n$.

What about the function $f(n)=a^n+b$ ?

> Do positive integers $a$ and $b$ exists such that $a^n+b$ is prime for every natural number $n\ge 1$ ?

I searched for long chains in order to find out whether there is an obvious upper bound. For example $4^n+4503$ is prime for $n=1,\ldots,14$.

Comment: I think there is no known strictly increasing function producing only prime numbers (and hence arbitrary large prime numbers) other than the Eratosthene sieve or the one extracting all the prime numbers from $a n+1$ or those kind of (very hardly computable) functions. So in general you'd like to prove if there are (or not) an infinity of primes in $f(n)$, but not that it outputs only primes.

Comment: It is known that there exists a real number $a$ such that the integer part of $a^{3^n}$ is prime for all $n\ge 1$. But since $a$ cannot be completely calculated, this formula does not count.

Comment: I guess this statement is general for any sequence of integers such that $f(n) \sim n \ln n$ ?

Comment: Does $a=1, b=p-1$ work? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to your question is **no**. For any $a>1,b\geq 1$ there will always exists $n$ such that $a^n+b$ is composite.

Suppose that $a+b$ is prime, (otherwise we are finished) and consider $n=a+b$ and look at $a^{a+b}+b$ modulo $a+b$. Then by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), which states that $$a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$$ for any prime $p$, it follows that $$a^{a+b}+b\equiv a+b\equiv 0\pmod{a+b},$$ and so $a^{a+b}+b$ is divisible by $a+b$ and hence it is composite.

Comment: So, in short, one or both of $n=1$ or $n=a+b$ will give a composite.

Answer (score 3):

If there were such a function, then we wouldn't be talking about "largest prime yet discovered". We'd have an infinite number of them at our disposal. So no... we have no such closed form function.